# Draw Title in a Figure!

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, draw

How do I add a title in big letters in the following figure using TikZ? I also take the question on how to dislocate this title up, down, right and left of the figure. Thanks a lot. 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image can be put inside a node and another node places the title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (img) {\includegraphics[width=20mm]{example-image-a}}
    (img.north) node[above] {\textbf{Title}}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

An alternative with option `label`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[label=above:\textbf{Title}]
    {\includegraphics[width=20mm]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```