# How to add a title to tikzpicture + smoother function lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know that my first question from the title has been asked several times, but when I try to apply the solutions from other the questions, they don't work.

What I want to achieve, is to add a title to these two functions:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,font=\footnotesize]
\fill [blue!10] (0,0) -- (0.55,0) -- (0.55,0.55) -- (0,0.55) -- cycle;
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$Quantity$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[above] {$Price$};
\coordinate (p1) at (0.55,0.55);
\draw[color=blue,domain=0.067:4.5] plot (\x,{(0.3)/(\x)});
\draw[dotted] (p1) -- (0.55,0) node[below] {$Q^*$};
\draw[dotted] (p1) -- (0,0.55) node[left] {$P^*$};
\fill[blue] (p1) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,font=\footnotesize]
\fill [blue!10] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,2) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$Quantity$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[above] {$Price$};
\coordinate (p1) at (1,2);
\draw[color=blue,domain=0:2] plot (\x,{(2-\x)*2});
\draw[dotted] (p1) -- (1,0) node[below] {$Q^*$};
\draw[dotted] (p1) -- (0,2) node[left] {$P^*$};
\fill[blue] (p1) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Optimal side A and B pricing under marginal costs, based on XXX}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Most solutions state that one should add \node + label to each of the tikzpictures, but I'm getting critical errors whenever I try to incorporate this. So my questions would be:

1) How can I add a title above each picture?

2) Regarding the convex curve in the left picture: there is an "edge" on the blue function - Any idea how this can be fixed?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: your example produces `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option \`H'.`and if I remove the H `Runaway argument?
{Optimal side A and B pricing under marginal costs, based on \end {fi\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@xdblarg.`

Comment: Thank you, I corrected this in the original code and works now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way would be to place a node relative to the `current bounding box`, as in the example below. You could of course use explicit coordinates as well, e.g. `\node at (2.5,5.2) {Some title};`.

For the plot, add `samples=100` or something like that. The default number of samples is 25, more samples gives smoother curves (and longer compile times). And an unrelated note, don't write `Price` and `Quantity` in math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,font=\footnotesize]
\fill [blue!10] (0,0) -- (0.55,0) -- (0.55,0.55) -- (0,0.55) -- cycle;
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {Quantity};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[above] {Price};
\coordinate (p1) at (0.55,0.55);
\draw[color=blue,domain=0.067:4.5,samples=100] plot (\x,{(0.3)/(\x)});
\draw[dotted] (p1) -- (0.55,0) node[below] {$Q^*$};
\draw[dotted] (p1) -- (0,0.55) node[left] {$P^*$};
\fill[blue] (p1) circle (2pt);
\node[above,font=\large\bfseries] at (current bounding box.north) {Some title};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,font=\footnotesize]
\fill [blue!10] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,2) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {Quantity};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[above] {Price};
\coordinate (p1) at (1,2);
\draw[color=blue,domain=0:2] plot (\x,{(2-\x)*2});
\draw[dotted] (p1) -- (1,0) node[below] {$Q^*$};
\draw[dotted] (p1) -- (0,2) node[left] {$P^*$};
\fill[blue] (p1) circle (2pt);
\node[above,font=\large\bfseries] at (current bounding box.north) {Some other title};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Optimal side A and B pricing under marginal costs, based on}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why your previous efforts to place a node didn't work is impossible to say as you didn't tell us what you tried.

Comment: Thank you so much! Both solutions worked. What I tried to do comes from the following [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326360/draw-title-in-a-figure) and is \node[label=above:\textbf{Title}]

Comment: @Daniel Well, that's different, there the plot is an image that is placed inside a node, which is the only thing in the `tikzpicture`, and the title is a label for that node. If you did `\node [label=above:title] {};` (you always have to have the node text in `{}`) the empty node would be placed at the default coordinate `(0,0)`, and `title` would be placed right above it. But you draw other stuff, so you need to specify the coordinates for the node.

Comment: Nice. I have found the following useful in a related context: ``\node[above,font=\large\bfseries]at ($(current bounding box.north west)+(1,1)$) {Some title};`` with ``\usetikzlibrary{calc}``